# fread sometimes returns wrong values with files larger than 4GiB

Tags: c++, c, fread

I'm trying to read a big binary file made of 30e6 positions, each with 195 doubles.
Since the file is too big to read all into memory, I'm reading it by chunks of 10000 positions. I then do some calculation with it and read the next chunk....

Since I need random access to the file, I've written a function to read a given chunk (unsigned int chunk) from the file and store it in **chunk_data. the function returns the total number of positions read.

```
unsigned int read_chunk(double **chunk_data, unsigned int chunk) {
    FILE *in_glf_fh;
    unsigned int total_bytes_read = 0;

    // Define chunk start and end positions
    unsigned int start_pos = chunk * 10000;
    unsigned int end_pos = start_pos + 10000 - 1;
    unsigned int chunk_size = end_pos - start_pos + 1;

    // Open input file
    in_glf_fh = fopen(in_glf, "rb");
    if( in_glf_fh == NULL )
        error("ERROR: cannot open file!");

    // Search start position
    if( fseek(in_glf_fh, start_pos * 195 * sizeof(double), SEEK_SET) != 0 )
        error("ERROR: cannot seek file!");

    // Read data from file
    for(unsigned int c = 0; c < chunk_size; c++) {
         unsigned int bytes_read = fread ( (void*) chunk_data[c], sizeof(double), 195, in_glf_fh);
         if( bytes_read != 195 && !feof(in_glf_fh) )
             error("ERROR: cannot read file!");
         total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
    }

    fclose(in_glf_fh);
    return( total_bytes_read/195 );
}
```

The problem is, after reading some chunks, `fread()` starts giving the wrong values!
Also, depending on the chunk size, the positions where `fread()` starts behaving strangely differs:

```
chunk of 1 pos, wrong at chunk 22025475
chunk of 10000 pos, wrong at chunk 2203
chunk of 100000 pos, wrong at chunk 221
```

Anyone has any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on your platform?

Comment: the title of the question should be meaningful. It will help users in summarizing your problem.

Comment: You have allocated memory for the chunks?

Comment: You are overflowing the temporary `int` that you pass to `fseek()`.

    30e6 * 195 * sizeof(double) =~= 46 billion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After determining that `30e6 positions` was not hex, and instead 30,000,000: consider the problem of `fseek()`:  The file has 46,800,000,000 bytes.  The plain vanilla `fseek()` (on 16- and 32-bit platforms) is limited to the first 2^32-1 bytes (=4,294,967,295).

Depending on the platform the program runs on, you might have to use `lseek64` or its equivalent.  On Linux, there are

- using `lseek()` with

  #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
- `llseek()`
- `lseek64()`

Comment: The limits of plain vanilla `fseek` depend on the platform; on many platforms, it will be 2*64 (minus some epsilon).  On the other hand, most platforms still have 32 bit ints and he's doing all of his arithmetic in `int` (or `unsigned int`), which will overflow.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Yep.  I have qualified my sentence.

Comment: Make it 2^31 - 1, though, the offset parameter is a `long`.